# Unable to get data at server even after giving it correctly through body in React

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, api, fetch-api

I'm implementing a user login system but when I'm sending request to my server but my server is receiving data as undefined. First I was doing it through proxy but even though after providing complete url it's not working and on submitting also it's get redirected to http://localhost:3000/login but it should be redirected to homepage on succesfull and if it not authorized it will alert to user.
<kbd>Client Side login</kbd>

```
const loginUser = async (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email:email,
        password:password,
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log("Data",data)
    if (data.status === 422 || !data) {
      console.log("Invalid cred");
      window.alert("Invalid Credentials");
    }
    if(data.status === 400){
      window.alert("wrong password");
    }
    else{
      window.alert("Login Suceesfuuly");
      console.log("Login success");
      history.push("/");
    }
    
  };
```

Here the case is even the data is invalid or not filled correctly it should show alert but it is getting redirected to http://localhost:3000/login and which is giving me some json response,the content of this page is:

```
{"error":"pls filled all the field"}
```

and the code for the server side login functionality

<kbd>Server side login</kbd>

```
 try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log("we got a request", email, password);
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(422).json({ error: "pls filled all the field" });
    }

    const userLogin = await User.findOne({
      $and: [{ email: email }],
    });
    if (!userLogin) {
      return res.status(422).json({ error: "User is not authorized" });
    }
    if (userLogin) {
      const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, userLogin.password);
      const token =  await userLogin.generateAuthToken();
      
      res.cookie('jwtoken', token, {
          expires: new Date(Date.now() + 25892000000),
          httpOnly:true
      })
      if (passwordMatch) {
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "login success" });
      } else {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: "The password is invalid" });
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
  }
```

Everytime i puting request from client side I'm getting this on server side

```
we got a request undefined undefined
```

Comment: have you set-up the bodyparser in backend ?

Comment: Open up developers console and check if clients request has o request body - if it does, then there is something wrong in your backend. As I see it's nodejs + express, so one idea could be that you haven't set up a body parser.

Answer (score 1):

Try console logging `req.body` in the server side. Then you will know the structure of the request body you are getting from the client before destructuring the request object. Check if you have body-parser in the server. And also I don't think you need to do `JSON.stringify()` in the post request.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things going on here.

```
if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(422).json({ error: "pls filled all the field" });
    }
```

You got an error from here, which means that either `email` or `password` are falsy. You can also check this by noting that you get email and password as `undefined`.

Some things to try:

1. Check if your Express server has body-parser added as middleware.
2. Check if you actually send some data from the email and password fields. You can log them in the client side before sending data.